# Blazor server - How can I get a parent component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component that is a child of `<AppointmentCompactFormContent>`. This is set up as follows:

```
<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm Model="@FormInfo" Context="EditFormContext" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <AppointmentCompactFormContent EnableValidation="true">
    </AppointmentCompactFormContent>
</Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>
```

I need to get that grandparent `<EditForm>` object. Is there a way to do that?

And let me explain why. I am using the Dev Express `DxScheduler` component. I need to have it validate the appointment form and due to how they changed the behavior of the DxScheduler events, doing this on the form submission is too late. So pre form submission I need to somehow call:

```
var isValidated = EditForm.EditContext.Validate()
```

But as the `EditForm` is deep inside the `DxScheduler` code, I don't have access to it.

If I can't do this, then I will need to do the validation myself property by property and also add my own validation display. So a lot of work for a sub-standard solution.

Comment: I almost hesitate to ask this of someone with your experience, but why do you want to go up the tree rather than have the parents provide the appropriate dependencies to their children?

Comment: @Logarr Very good question - I just updated to explain.

Comment: Back in the early days of Blazor ( about two years ago (?) ) you might provide a callback method so that the child could "talk to" the parent. Also you can pass a parameter to the child (basically a `this` reference) so the child has a reference on the parent and access to all its methods, which is less often advertised (it probably breaks some clean code rules!).

Comment: Big oof at that edit. While I have only worked with DevExpress's reporting system, I have been told by several people that their support is excellent. If you haven't done so already I suggest hitting up their forums/support as they might have a KB article on this already.

Comment: @Logarr I've used DevExpress for decades and think their products and support are superb. But they made a recent change where there's no way to have the form validation plus my additional validation on inserting or updating an appointment.

Comment: @topsail The problem is I have no access to the `EditForm` component. So I can't set it to pass anything down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditForm` component cascades the `EditContext` so in the child component you can do

```
[CascadingParameter]
private EditContext? CurrentEditContext { get; set; }
```

You can check here for an example of using the cascaded `EditContext`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#validator-components

Comment: Dimitris - you are my favorite person in the world! This is what makes SO so great - someone usually has a very clean simple solution to problems that I've spent hours trying to solve. Thank you.